Intuition for linear system of divisors?
I am currently studying Principles of Algebraic Geometry by Griffiths and Harris. On page 132 - 133,they defined a "linear system" in two ways. One for divisors, and one for line bundles (so the second one is more general).
Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold.

If $D$ is some divisor on $M$, let $\mathcal{L}(D)$ be the set of all meromorphic functions $f$ on $M$ such that $D+(f)$ is an effective divisor. Here, $(f)$ is the principal divisor associated to $f$. Then a linear system is defined to be a linear subspace of the projectivized space $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{L}(D))$.

If $L$ is a line bundle over $M$, then a linear system is defined to be a linear subspace of the projectivized space $\mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathcal{O}(L)))$, where $\mathcal{O}(L)$ is the sheaf of sections of $L$ and $H^0$ is its global section.


I understand that these definitions agree when $L$ is the line bundle associated to some divisor $D$. But what really are they? Why do we make such definitions? I want some intuition for them.
As a general fact about linear systems, the book page 137 also states Bertini's theorem. I was told that this version of Bertini's theorem would imply that if $V$ is any smooth hypersurface of $\mathbb{P}^n$, then for a generic hyperplane $H$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$, the intersection $H\cap V$ is smooth. Can somebody tell me how to deduce this from Bertini's theorem (on p.137 of Griffiths and Harris)? It would be great if you could spell this out explicitly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

On the set of divisors one has linear equivalence: $$D \sim D' \iff D - D' = (f) \quad \text{for some meromorphic function } f$$
One interesting question could be: Which effective divisors are linearly equivalent to a given divisor $D$?
By definition of $\mathcal L(D)$ this is exactly the set $$|D| := \{D+(f):f \in \mathcal L(D) \setminus \{0\}\}.$$
There is a canonical map
$$\pi:\mathcal L(D) \setminus \{0\} \to |D|, \quad f \mapsto D+(f).$$
Note that if $f,g$ are meromorphic functions, then $(f) = (g)$ if and only if $f = \lambda g$. This shows that $|D|$ is exactly the projectivization $\mathbb P(\mathcal L(D))$. So you can think of $\mathbb P(\mathcal L(D))$ as the set of effective divisors which are linearly equivalent to $D$.
And to be honest, I find it a bit miraculous that this happens to be a projective space!
Here is an important bit: The projective space $|D|$ is called a complete linear system. A general linear system is a linear subspace of $|D|$.

If you have a line bundle $L$, then every section $s \in H^0(M,L)$ defines an effective divisor $$s_0 = \{x \in M : s(x) = 0\}.$$
Again, scaling $s$ does not change its divisor.
In this way you can again identify $\mathbb P(H^0(M,L))$ with a set of effective divisors on $M$, all of which are linearly equivalent.

Here is the version of Bertini's theorem from Griffiths & Harris:

Bertini's Theorem. The generic element of a linear system is smooth away
from the base locus of the system.

The idea is that on $\mathbb P^n$ you have a linear system of hyperplanes. Note that every two hyperplanes are linearly equivalent. Also, this is the linear system of the line bundle $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$.
Exercise: Which meromorphic function translates between two hypherplanes?
Now if $V \subset \mathbb P^n$ is a submanifold, set $\mathcal O_V(1) = \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)|_V$. Hyperplane sections $H \cap V$ are then divisors of the linear system generated by the image of the map $$H^0(\mathbb P^n, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)) \to H^0(V, \mathcal O_V(1)).$$
Since the linear system of hyperplanes on $\mathbb P^n$ is base-point free, so is the induced linear system on $V$. It follows from Bertini's theorem that a general element is smooth.

For a first intuition I would recommend to think about linear systems of divisors in $\mathbb P^n$, i.e. hypersurfaces. Any two hypersurfaces of the same degree $d$ are linearly equivalent (why?), and the linear system is the projective space whose coordinates are the coefficients $c_\alpha$ of an equation $$\sum_{|\alpha| = d} c_\alpha x^\alpha = 0.$$ For example for $n=2$ and $d=3$ you get all cubic curves. Maybe try it out in an online calculator to see how the curves change when you play around with the coefficients.

Thank you, I now see the answer to my last question. But could you mention, in your answer, how to intuitively think of linear systems of divisors? Like how should I picture these things? For example I remember seeing someone say that they loosely represent "family of subvarieties." Why does that make sense?

@Sardines I added something about this.

Take the simplest case when $M$ is a compact complex manifold of dimension one (or a compact Riemann surface). Then the dimension of the space $\cal{L}(D)$ is related to the genus of the surface and can be determined using the Riemann-Roch theorem. If this dimension is $d$, it tells us that there are $d$ linearly independent meromorphic functions over $\mathbf{C}$ with prescribed bounds on the order of zeros and poles of the functions (at the points as given by the divisor $D$). So in the case of a linear system (as defined as a linear subspace of the projectivized space), if we know its dimension, that tells us something about the existence (or otherwise) of such functions in the projective setting.
